# Oracle no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Tags: sql, database, oracle, foreign-keys, create-table

```
Error starting at line : 25 in command -
CREATE TABLE Note (
    Note_ID NUMBER,
    Engineer_ID NUMBER,
    Project_ID NUMBER,
    Bug_ID NUMBER,
    Bug_Name varchar2(30),
    CONSTRAINT Note_PK PRIMARY KEY (Note_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Engineer_ID) REFERENCES Engineer(Engineer_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Project_ID) REFERENCES Project(Project_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Bug_ID) REFERENCES Bug(Bug_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Bug_Name) REFERENCES Bug(Bug_Name)
)
Error report -
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
*Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
           gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
           key constraint in the referenced table.
*Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
           catalog view
```

Cannot seem to find any way to fix this... could someone help? Need for an assignment soon. I have some more code beforehand but I just cant seem to find any sort of problem with it :?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is clear enough. For each foreign key defined in your table, the referenced table column needs to be `unique` or `primary key`.

So you want to ensure that all the following table columns do match this requirement:

```
Engineer(Engineer_ID)
Project(Project_ID)
Bug(Bug_ID)
Bug(Bug_Name)
```

Likely, the problem is with column `Bug_Name`; I would guess that this information is functionaly dependent of `Bug_ID`, that is already referenced by a foreign key: if so, then you just do not need to store it in the `Note` table (you can access it through the `Bug_ID` foreign key).

Comment: So I cannot use foreign key?

Comment: Or how would I actually write that out... still not quite sure what you mean, sorry...

Comment: @ChrisLloyd: the problem is with `Bug_Name`. It is neither unique, nor a primary key in table `Bug`. You should not be storing that information in the `Notes` table (see my updated answer).

Comment: Just tried removing the Bug_Name from it... still same error code.

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it haha. Less information in the table than I wanted but thank you for your help! Life saver